# ICS TimePicker sliders has weird see-thru styles

Tags: android, timepicker, theming

I'm experience a very weird behaviuor with the android `TimePicker` where the sliders are appearing to be transparent.

Below are two images:

1. When the list on the page is empty. As you can see, the sliders in the TimePicker in the bottom are transparent.
2. When the list is populated. This is even worse. The content of the list somehow are reflected 180 deg onto the transparent section of the sliders.

[image: Empty List]

[image: Populated List]

This is very frustrating. So far, I have no clue how this came to be. I'm also attaching my view's xml for reference. The theme I'm using is an unmodified `Theme.Sherlock.`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date_picker"
            >
        <ListView
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/availabilityListView"
                android:layout_above="@+id/add_more"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/suggest_more_time"
                android:id="@+id/add_more"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/suggestion_overlay">


        <DatePicker
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/time_picker"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:longClickable="false"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_suggestion"
                android:id="@+id/suggest_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```